# Как зарегистрировать тип с generic параметрами Unity Container?

Tags: c#, unity-container

У меня есть интерфейс, который имеет 2 generic параметра.

```
IStorage<TEntity, TKey>
```

И класс, который реализует интерфейс

```
SqlStorage<TEntity, TKey>
```

Как зарегистрировать их в Unity Container? На msdn написано сделать так:

```
container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IStorage<>),
    typeof(SqlStorage<>),
    new ContainerLifeTimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new object[]
        {
            new GenericParameter("TEntity"),
            new GenericParameter("TKey")
        }));
```

Но, VS ругается на неправильное количество параметров в typeof(IStorage<>) и typeof(Storage<>).

Что я делаю не так и как надо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас интерфейс и реализующий его тип имеют два типа-параметра, соответственно, писать надо так:

```
uc.RegisterType(typeof (IStorage<,>), typeof (SqlStorage<,>));
```